# How can I calculate uv coordinates for vertices if I know the vertex coordinate of my texture on a plane

Tags: opengl-es, coordinates, texture-mapping, vertex, uv-mapping

I'm trying to map a texture on a plane, I know the vertex coordinates for the texture, and the coordinates for the 4 vertices. Then how can I calculate the uv texture coordinates for the 4 vertices?

Here's a picture to show you what I'm trying to do,

[image]

The yellow with grid area is my texture, it is a square texture skewed into that shape. The green area is my plane that I want to map my texture on to. I know the vertex coordinates for point `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, and point `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`.

For example, if my texture is placed like this

[image]

Those are the vertex coordinates for all the points. Then the uv coordinates for point `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` should be `(-0.5f, -0.5f), (1.5f, -0.5f), (1.5f, 1.5f), (-0.5f, 1.5f)`

But if the texture is skewed like the first picture, how can I calculate the uv coordinates for point `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you trying to do this CPU or GPU? Assuming CPU what you could do is project the vertices of your skewed plane onto the green plane. If you think of the green plane as a screen which has a camera and therefore associated view and projection matrices you could project each point onto its surface and then find the distance from the origin which is in your case in the middle of the green plane.

From your tags it looks like you are using OpenGL ES, are you using fixed function or shaders? What maths library do you use? GLM has glm::project and glm::unproject which are basically what you want [here's](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.1/api/a00003.html) a link to info about that.

[Here's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection) some general information on what you want to do, you basically want to project from 3D to 2D and then find the relative distances on your plane.

Hope that helps.